# Breaking a PHP array into parts and running chunks asynchronously?

Tags: php, arrays, asynchronous

I would like to take an array and break it up into chunks (closure $r accomplishes this)

```
/**
 * Breaks an array into bits
 *
 * @param $list
 * @param $p
 * @return array
 */
$r = function ($list, $p)
{
    $ll = count( $list ); $pl = floor( $ll / $p ); $pt = $ll % $p; $r = []; $m = 0;

    for ($px = 0; $px < $p; $px++)
    {
        $inc = ($px < $pt) ? $pl + 1 : $pl; $r[$px] = array_slice( $list, $m, $inc );
        $m += $inc;
    }

    return $r;
};

$hosts = [
    'devhost-0',
    'devhost-1',
    'devhost-2',
    'devhost-3',
    'devhost-4',
    'devhost-5',
    'devhost-6',
    'devhost-7',
    'devhost-8',
    'devhost-9',
    'devhost-10',
    'devhost-11',
    'devhost-12',
    'devhost-13',
    'devhost-14',
    'devhost-15',
    'devhost-16',
    'devhost-17',
    'devhost-18',
    'devhost-19',
    'devhost-20',
    'devhost-21',
    'devhost-22',
    'devhost-23',
    'devhost-24',
    'devhost-25',
    'devhost-26',
    'devhost-27',
    'devhost-28',
    'devhost-29',
    'devhost-30',
    'devhost-31',
    'devhost-32',
    'devhost-33',
    'devhost-34',
    'devhost-35',
    'devhost-36',
];

$hosts = $r($hosts, 6); // chunks of six
```

This will break the above [array into chunks of 5-6](http://pastebin.com/nKJTc4yN), from here I would like to run each of the chunks at the same time
with a simple method, lets say this ping closure below.

```
/**
 * Polls host
 *
 * @param $host
 * @param $port
 * @param $timeout
 * @return bool
 */
$ping = function ($host, $port, $timeout)
{
    $errno = $errstr = false; // silence....
    return (! @fSockOpen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout))
        ? false
        : true;
};
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this though? I would assume that I would be using [pcntl_fork()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) or [pthreads](http://pthreads.org/) but am uncertain as to how I should be setting this up? I have read multiple articles on running processes asynchronously but I am having issues finding one using an array as parts in an example.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `array_chunk`?

Comment: I don't use array_chunk() as I cannot predict how many chunks will be created, it will divide all parts of the array into chunks of six instead of allowing me the ability to make six sub arrays to use. Being able to control the thread count now instead of later seemed like a smart. array_chunk() also give a fairly uneven count per array as all would have six members save the remainder which will have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this could work (based off threading example here http://acm.msu.ru/mkoshp/php-chunked-xhtml/pthreads.tutorials.html )

```
$hosts = [
    'devhost-0',
    'devhost-1',
    'devhost-2',
    'devhost-3',
    'devhost-4',
    'devhost-5',
    'devhost-6',
    'devhost-7',
    'devhost-8',
    'devhost-9',
    'devhost-10',
    'devhost-11',
    'devhost-12',
    'devhost-13',
    'devhost-14',
    'devhost-15',
    'devhost-16',
    'devhost-17',
    'devhost-18',
    'devhost-19',
    'devhost-20',
    'devhost-21',
    'devhost-22',
    'devhost-23',
    'devhost-24',
    'devhost-25',
    'devhost-26',
    'devhost-27',
    'devhost-28',
    'devhost-29',
    'devhost-30',
    'devhost-31',
    'devhost-32',
    'devhost-33',
    'devhost-34',
    'devhost-35',
    'devhost-36',
];
class Devhost_worker extends Thread{
    public $jobs;
        public function __construct($jobs) {
       $this->jobs = $jobs;
    }
        public function run() {
        //do your stuff with the $this->jobs  here.
    }
}
$chunks=array_chunk($hosts,6,true);
$threads=array();
$i=0;
foreach($chunks as $chunk){
    $threads[$i]=new Devhost_worker($chunk);
    $threads[$i]->start();
    ++$i;
}
```

Comment: Plus one for a solution, if no better answers come up I will accept =)

Comment: $i is not incremented

Answer (score 0):

Something that I came up with just a while ago, will not accept but will post as a possible solution to my question. I was able to ping 4k of my servers in about 1 minute or so.

```
<?php

define('APP_DIR', dirname(__DIR__)); // autloads in non-sample script....

$hosts = explode("\n", file_get_contents(APP_DIR . '/data/test.txt'));

/**
 * Processes in Parallel.
 *
 * Run a function (with no return result) on each item in an array in parallel.
 * Note: This function is only useful if order is not important, and you don't
 * need any return values from the function (i.e. no inter-process communication).
 *
 * @param mixed   $func  A closure function to apply to each item in parallel.
 * @param array   $arr   The array to apply function to.
 * @param integer $procs Number of processes to run in parallel.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function parallelize($func, array $arr, $procs = 4)
{
    $chunks   = array_chunk($arr, ceil((count($arr) / $procs)));
    $pid      = -1;
    $children = [];
    foreach ($chunks AS $items)
    {
        $pid = pcntl_fork();

        switch ($pid)
        {
            case (-1): die ('Unable to fork');

            case (0): // We are the child process. Pass a chunk of items to process.
                array_walk($items, $func);
                exit(0);

            default: // We are the parent.
                $children[] = $pid;
                break;
        }
    }

    // Wait for children to finish.
    foreach ($children AS $pid)
    {
        // We are still the parent.
        pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status);
    }
}

/**
 * Polls host
 *
 * @param $host
 * @param $port
 * @param $timeout
 * @return bool
 */
$ping = function ($host, $port, $timeout)
{
    $errno = $errstr = false; // silence....
    return (! @fSockOpen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout))
        ? false
        : true;
};


/**
 * Simple true false return on pinging...
 *
 * @param $host
 * @return bool
 */
$tap = function ($host) USE ($ping)
{
    if (! $ping($host, 22, 3))
    {
        echo "[fail] does not exist\n";
        return false;
    }

    else
    {
        echo "[good] exists\n";
        return true;
    }
};

parallelize($tap, $hosts, 20); // do work....
```